# How to Connect an iOS Web App to a Database

Tags: javascript, ios, database

I am working on an iOS app for the iPhone, iPad and Mac desktop. I would like the web app to be able to save data to a database so that it is accessible on all the different platforms.

Doing research, I have found that PHP does not work with PhoneGap. So, unfortunately I can't go that route.

How could I connect a web app to a database using javascript? I could do local storage, but I would really like to functionality of a database.

Thanks!

Comment: check out couchDB, http://www.couchbase.com/mobile or http://pouchdb.com/

Comment: Is this a database on the device locally, or in the server backend?  All of the main mobile platforms come with sqlLite.